# Questions about "Address-of operator" (&) and arrays in c and c++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I found a difference when compiling in c versus when I compile in c++ that I don't fully understand... Let's say I declare an array of char of size 5:

```
char my_array[5];
```

From my understanding, "my_array" is effectively a char pointer, which allows me to do this:

```
char* a = my_array;
```

Now, I understand that when I declared my array, I allocated 5 bytes only (one for each values in it), which means that "&my_array" should not exist, because there is no allocated memory for a pointer to my_array. To prove that, I did this:

```
char* b = &my_array; // compiler error in c++, not in c
char** c = &my_array; // compiler error in c++, not in c
```

I don't get the difference, why would c allow that? Still, let's say I want to convert my char[5] to char*, without using the method for a, I found that I can also do:

```
char* c = (char*)&my_array; // works both in c and c++
```

That one I really don't understand. Have I not determined that "&my_array" doesn't exist? More alarmingly, these 2 lines returns the same exact value:

```
// a and c have the same value (both in c and c++)
char* a = my_array;
char* c = (char*)&my_array;
```

Next, let's say I want to execute those 5 bytes at run-time, so I declare a new type:

```
// pFunc is a pointer to function returning void
typedef void (*pFunc)();
```

Then I tried declaring a pointer to function that would execute my array of bytes:

```
pFunc pFunc1 = (pFunc)&my_array; // works, but I don't really understand why
pFunc pFunc2 = (pFunc)my_array;  // compiler error in c++, not in c
```

Suddenly, not only is &my_array compiling without problem, but it's also the only way to make this works in c++ (that I know of). Anyone mind explaining to me what is going on? Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*pFunc)();

int main()
{
    char my_array[5];

    char* a = my_array;
    char* b = &my_array; // compiler error in c++, not in c
    char* c = (char*)&my_array;
    char** d = &my_array; // compiler error in c++, not in c
    char** e = (char**)&my_array;

    pFunc pFunc1 = (pFunc)&my_array; // works, but I don't really understand why
    pFunc pFunc2 = (pFunc)my_array;  // compiler error in c++, not in c

    printf("char*:\n");
    printf("0x%X\n", a);
    printf("0x%X\n", b);
    printf("0x%X\n", c);
    printf("0x%X\n", d);
    printf("0x%X\n", e);
    printf("\n");

    while(1);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: ""my_array" is effectively a char pointer" this is incorrect

Comment: What do you get if you compiler C code with a Java compiler? Please read the C-tag info page. C and C++ are different languages. A simple search for "C C++ differences" will answer your question. And there is a good reason an array is called "array" and not "pointer" (and vice-versa).

Comment: @Slava Well, that depends on the context since it can decay to a `char*` but it can also just be a `char[5]`.

Comment: @cad: Yes, it **decays** (i.e. is automatically converto to a point er to ist first element). But is **is** not the same as a pointer.

Comment: @cad literal `0` can decay to `nullptr` but you cannot say 0 is effectively a `nullptr`.

Comment: And casting a function pointer to/from an object pointer is undefined behaviour in C.

Comment: @Slava: IIRC, it is some C legacy that C++ also treats `0` assigned to a pointer as a _null pointer constant_. C++11 added the `nullptr` keyword to get eventually (within the next 2-3 decades:-( rid of this nonsense. I wish C11 had followed that.

Comment: So in my code when it compiles in c, but not in c++, it's because c++ flat out says I can't do that, while c just didn't define the behavior of my code? Also, why would I have to put a "&" operator to convert my_array from char[5] to function pointer?

Comment: The need to use a cast should be a clear indicator you did something wrong. Do not use a cast unless you **fully** understand all implications! There is a reason your compiler warns about type missmatches. And enable warnings; your C compiler should complain, too.

Comment: And just because your code compiles does not mean it is correct. Please informs us if you found a tool/language which can proof that for every non-trivial program and terminates properly within - say - some months (preferably less).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array in C++ is not a pointer.  When a pointer of the appropriate type is initialized using the array's name (such as when the array is passed to a function argument of the appropriate pointer type), it will decay into a pointer, but it is not itself a pointer.

When you declare `char my_array[5]`, you are creating an array of 5 `char`s; no pointer is created, but a `char[5]` exists and can be pointed to by other pointers.

If you do `char* a = my_array;`, `my_array` will decay into a pointer; a new `char*` is created pointing to the first element of `my_array`.
`char* b = &my_array;` fails because `my_array` isn't a `char`, and thus `&my_array` isn't a `char*`.  `char** d = &my_array;` fails since `my_array` isn't a `char*`, and thus `&my_array` isn't a `char**`.  `&my_array` is a `char (*)[5]` (pointer to an array of 5 `char`s).  These "work" in C because C only requires the compiler issue a warning for implicit conversion between unrelated pointer types, but C++ does not allow these implicit conversions at all; they result in a compilation error.  You need an explicit cast in C++, but even then the behavior is undefined if you dereference the resulting pointer.

Finally, `pFunc pFunc1 = (pFunc)&my_array;` "works" on platforms that represent function pointers and object pointers similarly (most modern systems), but it isn't required to work on all platforms.  Again, using the resulting pointer will invoke undefined behavior.
`pFunc pFunc2 = (pFunc)my_array;` actually compiles as well using GCC, but fails to compile under MSVC.  I'm not actually sure which compiler's behavior is correct, but either way the result is unlikely to be anything useful.

Comment: "because C allows implicit conversion between unrelated pointer types" - it doesn't. It's a constraint violation that requires a diagnostic. GCC just happens to issue a warning rather than an error.

Comment: @T.C. It requires a diagnostic, but GCC is still "allowed" to let the code compile.

Comment: @PCLuddite By that logic, C "allows" everything under the sun.

Comment: Updated to mention that a warning is required to be emitted in C.

Comment: Best answer so far. However, on the function pointers, you are a bit incorrect: Casts to/from function pointers from/to other types are not guaranteed to work in any way, since a function pointer can be a fundamentally different beast than a data pointer. I remember that on PPC Macs, a function pointer actually consisted of *two* pointers, one to point to the global data table (TOC), the other to point to the code. You cannot cast a `char*` to such a function pointer. I guess, `gcc` allows that because the linux people need and use it (take a look at libdl).

Comment: Yes, GCC and MSVC both allow such conversions, but I edited to note that it is not required to work.

Comment: "but either way the result is unlikely to be anything useful.". In my case I have to execute variable bytes at runtime, I'm not sure how I could do that any other way?

Comment: If you're trying to attack some sort of code injection vulnerability then you've moved out of the realm of "how does C++ work?" and into the realm of "how does this particular implementation happen to implement the constructs required by C++?".  Unless this is to learn about application security, I can't think of any legitimate reason to create a something like that.

Comment: I'm adding capabilities to a specific program I don't have the source code of (not for commercial use, just for me). I inject my code in it at runtime, replace 5 bytes (which I save in a char array) by a jump to my own function, my function does it's thing (mainly intercept some data and do stuff) then at the end of my function I simply execute the 5 bytes previously saved. That way, the program works exactly as if I didn't modify anything.

Comment: This is still not right. Neither the C nor the C++ standard distinguishes between "warnings" and "errors". The requirement is simply "a diagnostic", which can be anything the implementation says is one, including, say, the character `a`. It's up to the implementation to decide which problems result in errors and which in warnings (the one exception: in C, a source file containing an unskipped `#error` directive must not be successfully translated).

Answer (score 1):

When an array is defined then space is allocated for its element in memory. The whole space, in your case `5` bytes, is allocated for array. Therefore, space is allocated for arrays elements as well as array itself.

It should be noted that an array is not a pointer and vice-versa. `my_array` is an array and not a pointer. In most cases an array convert to a pointer to its first element, but it does not imply that arrays are pointers.

The address of array `my_array` is of type `char (*)[5]`, a pointer to an array of 5 `char`s. It is incompatible with type `char **` and `pFunct`. Assigning incompatible pointer types causes error.

Comment: That answers most of it, but I still don't understand why "pFunc pFunc2 = (pFunc)my_array;" would not work?

Comment: @MyUsername112358: As I already commented on your question: Think about the meaning of the word "undefined", as in _undefined behaviour_.

Comment: I thought the undefined behavior was casting &my_array to char*? What I don't understand is why is "char* b = &my_array;" undefined behavior, yet the only way I can cast my_array to function pointer is by using &my_array that way: "pFunc pFunc1 = (pFunc)&my_array;", and yet this doesn't work: pFunc pFunc2 = (pFunc)my_array;.

Comment: @MyUsername112358 Have you ever thought for a second about what you were trying to do? "only way I can cast my_array to function pointer", I mean, what? Why would you ever want to cast a char array to a function pointer? I can not imagine **any** use case for that...

Comment: So that I can execute those arrays at runtime, as I said in my original post... I'm injecting code in a running executable, I replace 5 bytes of the executable by a jump to my own function in the code I injected. I store those 5 bytes in a char array. My function do it's thing, then executes the 5 bytes at the end before returning to the executable. That way I can execute my function without modifying in any way the targeted executable. Not sure why you thought that was relevant to ask, but here you go.